# jQuery length > 0

Tags: jquery

I desided to make my code clearer by replacing

    `if (wrappedSet.length > 0)`


to something like

    `if (wrappedSet.exists())`


Is any native jq function for this? Or the only way is to extend it using $.fn.exists = ... ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could simply use

```
if (wrappedSet.length)
```

That will evaluate to TRUE if you have 1 or more elements and to FALSE if you have 0 elements

Answer (score 4):

The function [`size`](http://api.jquery.com/size) does exactly this.  On the other hand, why do you want to do this?  The extra function call would reduce performance (albeit by an infinitesimally small amount) with no particular gain.

You could just do this:

```
if (wrappedSet.length) {
```

since `0` evaluates to `false` and any other number evaluates to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You're not the first one ;-)

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/selector-exists-would-be-a-nice-addition

And `$.fn.exists =` looks like the way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

there's no native jquery function for it, you'll have to do an exists function like you said.

here's a link to a discussion in jquery about it:

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/selector-exists-would-be-a-nice-addition

its best to just use selector.length like the otehrs said. saves you the extra () :P